# Faster way to eval multiple strings javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below evaluates any code within "{{" and "}}", I managed to do it, but it is very slow, how to achieve the same result but in a faster way?

I'm not very familiar with regex replacement or something similar, so I'm struggling to get a better result.

```js
console.time("Time");

String.prototype.eval = function(){
  if(this.includes("{{") && this.includes("}}")){
    const result = [];
    const str = this.split("{{");
    
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      if(i === 0){
        result.push(str[i]);
        continue;
      }
      result.push(Function(`return ${str[i].split("}}")[0]}`)());
      result.push(str[i].split("}}")[1]);    
    }
    
    return result.join("");
  }
  return this;
}

const person = { name:"John Doe", age:55 };
const func = () => "cool!!";

console.log(`Hi {{person.name}}, you are {{person.age}} years old, {{func()}}`.eval());

console.timeEnd("Time");
```

Comment: Why not use template litteral notation? i.e: if you get your template string from somewhere else you can do: `eval('\`' + "Hi ${person.name}" + '\`');`. This way, you can ditch your entire `String.prorotype.eval` function. If your String is hard coded in your JS, then just do `console.log(\`Hi ${person.name}\`)`

Comment: Because those texts will be in the database. In this way facilitating translation into several languages by concentrating all the text in a single document.

Comment: And you're not able to store `"Hi ${person.name}"` in your database? Then you can do `eval('\`' + stringFromDB + '\`');`

Comment: I didn't think about that , I'll try it

Comment: but anyway, that wouldn’t be the only use, I could create custom commands for my discord bot in the future that wouldn’t necessarily be evaluated, but replaced with other strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this with RegEx, but I don't see it saved some time.

```js
console.time("Time");

String.prototype.eval = function() {
    return this.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (match, key) => Function(`return ${key}`)());
}

const person = {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 55
};
const func = ()=>"cool!!";

console.log(`Hi {{person.name}}, you are {{person.age}} years old, {{func()}}`.eval());

console.timeEnd("Time");
```